# Enumerating FT2232 channels

Tags: usbserial

FT2232 supports two (almost) identical channels, A and B. FT_ListDevices(...) sees them as two devices, 0 and 1. How can I be sure which of them is A? One of my computers sees A as 0, but the second sees A as 1 on the same chip. Is there a way to have them enumerated in a predictable way?